# Problems viewing large numbers in Excel (Scientific Notation) in 'Text' formatted cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem and havnt managed to find a solution online and was hoping I'd get lucky and someone could help.

I have a database application that exports a large dataset to .xlsx
A VBA application then maps this data into another Excel application.

When the data is exported out of the original database application, this process is outside of my control. All the cells have a 'General' cell format and we have some large numbers such as `172627108914` which is the serial number for a piece of equipment. In the exported xlsx file, this serial number is represented as `1.72627E+11`.

The next stage of the process copies this data into another worksheet which has all cells formatted as text. The value is copied over but the value stays the same and the format of the cell changes from Text to General.

Does anyone know what I have to do to change to remove the scientific notation?

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Change cell format from `General` to `Text` for Serial numbers might fix your issue.

Comment: One this I have noticed, is when the cell's format is changed to text and I double click on the value and then click off the cell. The value I want remains in the cell with a warning triangle telling me the number is formatted as text. If I don't double click the cell, the scientific notation remains in the cell

Comment: that warning doesn't hurt. It's a warning only.

Comment: thanks, the problem is I need to automate this so the application at the end of the chain displays an accurate serial number to the user

Comment: Well there are several tutorials how to convert numbers into text with VBA. Did you try anything yourself at all?

Answer (score 2):

Append a single apostrophe to the front of the number. That will force Excel to read the number in 'text' format automatically, and the apostrophe will not show up at the front of the number when it's displayed.

[image]

Comment: Not a criticism, but a comment since you used a 16 digit number.  When I was investigating a problem like this years ago, not only was the problem that the data was converted to a number, but Excel truncated it to 15 significant digits.  We found that when a customer paid with American Express (15 digits), we could recover the full number from the numeric value.  For Visa and MasterCard, we needed to compute the 16th digit and add it back in (which worked if the first 15 were accurate).  Hopefully the original poster has posted a number representative of the size they are encountering.

Comment: That's super interesting; it was only random chance that I included a 16-digit number here. A few years back, I was having to get a 22-digit unique ID and was running into similar problems. I feel like the apostrophe ended up being the fix because excel never got a chance to import the field and convert it to a number so the significant digits persisted upon import. How were you computing the final digit on the cc numbers? Does the Luhn algorithm allow you to compute the 16th digit with certainty when the prior 15 are known?

Comment: Yes.  Thankfully the check digit was the last digit in the number otherwise we would have had to do some real thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, in the end some VBA code was written to convert all fields in the original export to text then iterate over each cell and rewriting the value from the formula line. This has resulted in a correctly formatted worksheet to pass to the second application